# Copying tables mysql

Tags: php, sql

I am newbie to sql advance and i am trying to insert rows to one table by selecting from another one. But some bug is coming out.

Here is my problem
So i have two tables

```
table1 having id(autoincrement), names
table2 having id(autoincrement), names
```

Now at starting table1 is empty and table2 having 2 rows

```
1,'myself'
2,'yourself'
```

So the problem starts here
When i execute following query

```
Insert into table1 (names) select (names) from table2
```

So now both rows of table2 must be copied to table1
Ya its working fine.
But what about  autoincrement value of id?
By till now table1 autoincrement id should store 3 since next row to be inserted should have id 3

But its not working like expected so table1 autoincrement id stores 4 i.e, `1(current id value)+2*(no of rows inserted)-1`
So next time when i execute same query it inserts row with id 4. Skips id=3.
This is problem hope you all got what i am talking about.

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2`

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead an copy your data over, and then you can modify the starting auto_inc to whatever you choose.

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter Table will take around 1 sec as it first creates shadow of the table then the query is processed and if the no. of rows of table goes above then it may take around 20-30 sec. so I dont think that alter is good answer for this problem. Hope someone will help you with insert command such as:
Insert into table1 set id = 1; etc...